Non-deterministic execution plan on Postgres
Fairly simple schema:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Queue(
   Id             BIGSERIAL        NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   SendAt         TIMESTAMP(3)     NOT NULL,
   Payload        TEXT             NOT NULL,
   KeyId          BIGINT               NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS Queue_sendAt_ch_idx ON Queue (SendAt, KeyId);

Executing the following sometimes gives me (parallel) sequential table scan, sometimes a nice index scan. What gives?
BEGIN;

INSERT INTO Queue 
(id, sendat, payload, KeyId)
SELECT "id", now()-("id"||'ms')::INTERVAL, 'random payload', ("id" * 0.8)::bigint
FROM generate_series(1,200000) id;

analyze Queue;

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers)
SELECT Id
       FROM Queue
     WHERE KeyId           = 15
       AND SendAt         <= now()
       ORDER BY SendAt ASC
       LIMIT 1;
ROLLBACK;

(in docker postgres:16.3-bullseye)
EDIT:
Adding execution plans. I emphasize, the question is not why the plans are what they are. It's why I get different plans for same query.
Limit  (cost=0.42..3518.43 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=27.851..27.852 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1373
  ->  Index Scan using queue_sendat_ch_idx on queue  (cost=0.42..3518.43 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=27.849..27.849 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((sendat <= now()) AND (keyid = 15))
        Buffers: shared hit=1373
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=52 read=1
Planning Time: 0.408 ms
Execution Time: 27.872 ms

and after a few runs:
Limit  (cost=5792.44..5792.45 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=19.846..23.651 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=3334
  ->  Sort  (cost=5792.44..5792.45 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=19.844..23.649 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: sendat
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
        Buffers: shared hit=3334
        ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..5792.43 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=4.843..23.642 rows=1 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=3334
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on queue  (cost=0.00..4792.33 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=5.451..10.427 rows=0 loops=3)
                    Filter: ((keyid = 15) AND (sendat <= now()))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 66666
                    Buffers: shared hit=3334
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=26
Planning Time: 0.392 ms
Execution Time: 23.673 ms


I think it has to do with timing, try to add SELECT pg_sleep(10); (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/1AILyhHO   with help from:Delay or Wait-For Statement ) and check if you still can reproduce this behavior.,

I did try SELECT pg_sleep(1);, same effect. 1e9 nanoseconds not enough?

it's the same with SELECT pg_sleep(10)

ok, that it is probably not the timing....

I am seeing: Workers Planned: 2   ;  Workers Launched: 2   ;   Parallel Seq Scan on queue  (always after 10 attempts...)

You left out the important part, the output of the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers) for each case.

right... then my question is why not an index scan, but that's a different question.

the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers) is not important. The important thing is it's different in sequential runs. Even with pg_sleep(10);, I swear.

What is different? The EXPLAIN PLAN or the results of your query ?

The EXPLAIN PLAN.

@milan the EXPLAIN PLAN output is important, along with the actual statistics of SendAt. This query can't take advantage of indexing. It has to scan either the entire table or the entire index to find rows that match KeyId=15 as all rows match the other condition, SendAt <= now(). The query analyzer may decide it's not worth using the index. The expression now()-("id"||'ms') can easily generate skewed values that in turn will affect the statistics of the first index column, SendAt.


I cannot replicate, it always does a parallel sequential scan. 2) 200000 is small enough that a sequential plan is generally going to be sufficient. 3) The output of the plan matters, especially in your case where you see different outputs. Also because in the end the important part is Execution Time: 10.251 ms, which we are not seeing.


Most likely a configuration issue, random_page_cost that doesn't reflect the real difference in performance between random IO and sequential IO. Use SET random_page_cost TO 1.1; -- or something like that for a different setting and most likely different query plan.

@panagiotis How exactly does now()-("id"||'ms') generate skewed values?

The precision of now() is 1μs, not 1ms. The expression rounds the actual values up and ends up with values that are at best within 200s of each other. I don't know how PostgreSQL calculates statistics for timestamps that are that close to each other. The cost of the two possible execution plans may be so close that tiny differences in the values result in a different plan

Is it possible to reverse the order of the columns in your index? I think an index on (KeyId, SendAt) would fit your query much better.

@Panagiotis lacking a better explanation, I would take yours as correct, if you post it. Others are trying to answer something that was not asked in the first place.

What is the actual problem? Both give total time less the 3/100 second, with the sequential scans being somewhat faster.

@Belayer database scalability problems aren't about duration. The OP's example is just a demonstration. Bad execution plans take more resources and worse, scale far worse than good execution plans because they cause more concurrency conflicts.

@Belayer and when someone tries to use a table as a queue, the problems can become a lot worse. With a bad execution plan, trying to pop/seek the first item in Queue 15 would affect the entire table, or get blocked by the "pop" operations on other "queues"
